# Downloading Multiple Files Parallelly or Asynchronously in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, file, asynchronous, java-6

Here I am trying to download multiple files one after another:

Environment - Java 1.6

```java
public List<Attachment> download(List<Attachment> attachments)
{
  for(Attachment attachment : attachments) {
    attachment.setDownStatus("Failed");
    String destLocation = "C:\Users\attachments";
    try {
        String attUrl = attachment.getUrl();
        String fileName = attachment.getFileName();            
        URL url = new URL(attUrl);
        File fileLocation = new File(destLoc, fileName);
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, fileLocation);
        if(fileLocation.exists()) {
           attachment.setDownStatus("Completed");
         }
       } catch(Exception e) {
          attachment.setDownStatus("Failed");
       } finally {
          attachment.setDestLocation(destLocation);
       }
   }
  return attachments;
}
```

I am downloading the file from provided URL (http://cdn.octafinance.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/google-hummingbird.jpg).

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, fileLocation);
```

The above code does its downloading job perfectly, without any issues.

**My Problem:**
If the list of attachments are more it will take more time, so I would like to make it an **asynchronous or parallel process** instead of downloading sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, after carefully looking, Boris' code is faulty and will indeed not set some stuff sometimes. Here's a better version that fixes that:

```
public List<Attachment> download(List<Attachment> attachments) {
  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
  List<Future<Attachment>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Attachment>>();
  for (final Attachment attachment : attachments) {
    futures.add(executorService.submit(new Callable<Attachment>() {
      @Override
      public Attachment call() throws Exception {
        return doDownload(attachment);
      }
    }));
  }
  for (Future<Attachment> future: futures) {
    try {
      future.get();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      // Do something
    }
  }
  return attachments;
}

private Attachment doDownload(Attachment attachment) throws Exception {
  attachment.setDownStatus("Failed");
  attachment.setDestLocation("C:\\Users\\attachments");
  String attUrl = attachment.getUrl();
  String fileName = attachment.getFileName();
  URL url = new URL(attUrl);
  File fileLocation = new File(attachment.getDestLocation(), fileName);
  FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, fileLocation);
  if (fileLocation.exists()) {
    attachment.setDownStatus("Completed");
  }
  return attachment;
}
```

However, this is absolutely not optimal given your structure of `Attachment` and how you use it. I did not fix that: I only answered the question as it was asked.

Answer (score 6):

Use Java 8 Streams in combination with [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)

```
public List<Attachment> download(List<Attachment> attachments) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(attachments.size());

    return forkJoinPool.submit(() -> processAttachments(attachments)).get();
}

private List<Attachment> processAttachments(List<Attachment> attachments) {
    return attachments.stream().parallel().map(attachment -> processSingleAttachment(attachment)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private Attachment processSingleAttachment(Attachment attachment){
     //business logic to download single attachment
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Vishal, My project is based on Java 1.6, it would be good if you could able to provide solution based on java 1.6

Comment: Oh , I didn't see the Java version mentioned earlier. In that case the solution by Boris below looks good to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
public List<Attachment> download(List<Attachment> attachments)
{
  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
  for(final Attachment attachment : attachments){
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
          try{
            String attUrl = attachment.getUrl();
            String fileName = attachment.getFileName();
            String destLocation = "C:\Users\attachments";
            URL url = new URL(attUrl);
            String fileLocation = new File(destLoc, fileName);
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, fileLocation);
            if(fileLocation.exists()) {
              attachment.setDownStatus("Completed");
            }
          }
          catch(Exception e){
            attachment.setDownStatus("Failed");
          }
        }
    });
 }
 executorService.shutdown();
 return attachments;
}
```

Comment: This is an I/O-bound task. The number of available processors is a bad choice (or at least, not a good choice) for the pool size. Instead, use the number of files you want to download at once.

Comment: Also, you might want to wait for all attachments to finish before returning. Also, you probably want to shut down the thread pool when done (or reuse the same thread pool for every call).

Comment: Each attachment has a `downStatus` which can be used to monitor downloaded files.

Comment: @Boris, the suggested code runs faster than my code, But this code doesn't guarantees about downStatus, some times for some attachments i am getting 'null'. is there any way to get out of this issue.

Comment: @Uppicharla your original code doesn't guarantee that `downStatus` is not `null`. So why do you expect that this code makes such a guarantee?

Comment: @Olivier, Actually i posted some part of my actual code, Now i updated my post, please take a look once.

Comment: I applied the Boris approach to my code, after that i observed some times      'downStatus' is coming as 'null'.

Comment: you have to wait until it got initialized

Comment: @Boris, One more observation, `attachment.setDestLocation(destLocation);` is also setting null in some cases.